# How to perform an action on a database on certain times

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a database which I want to edit every day at a certain time. Let's say I have a database with: Id - Day - Activity

Example:
Every day at 9.00 hour, I want to delete all activities from the day before.

I have an ASP.NET Web Form web application, which I use to make the activities and fill the database with.

The databse is MSSQL.

How is this achieved easily?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler, sorry

Comment: U can use Job Agent of SQL server for reference check this link.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this as a [job on the server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

You can schedule jobs to run at specific times, which can run specified T-SQL commands. These jobs have logging, alerting etc as required. the MSDN should be a good guide to creating it.